# How to update a list of elements in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a list of objects. These objects and some of their properties are displayed on a gridview. User is able to add, remove, and change properties of any selected object.

The update approach is done at the save button click event (and not promptly with the actions taken).

What is the best way to update a list that may include added objects, deleted objects, and objects with modified properties in my Web API 2 using Entity Framework?

Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Customers class:

```
Public Class Customers
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

PUT Method for Customers thus far:

```
ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutCustomersViewModel(CustomersViewModel custViewModel)
{
   if(!ModelState.IsValid)
       return BadRequest(ModelState);

   // Not sure how to iterate thru the list and update or add accordingly


   _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

   try
   {
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
   {
       foreach(var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
       {
           foreach(var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
           {
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
           }
       }
   }
   catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
   {
        return NotFound();

        throw;
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

I can remove all items and re-add them but I think this is an incorrect approach. Are there any way to compare and only add/update change/missing elements?

Answer (score 2):

This is just my point of view, if it's hard to implement maybe it's because  the method try to do too much.

This approach will made a crapy code with maintenance issues.

The better way should be to split this in 3 method create, update and delete.

And put this action directly on the line of your datagrid or catch event on datagrid change for apply changement properly on your save method in your view.

Comment: Ideally you are correct, however, business requirement indicates, unfortunately, to allow users to play with the content (make changes, delete, and add) to get what they want before actually saving it. Another drawback is a database transaction for every action user takes and that would be way too many for this grid.

Comment: yes i know, maybe i looking for something like event sourcing and the save will send your events and your entrypoint should execute them

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to remove and re-add entities--that might actually delete what you have in the database and re-add new ones.

You could iterate through the objects to find the ones that are in both (update), and the ones that are in the target but not the source (delete), and the ones in the source but not in the target (create).  While you go you can make the changes in the db context and then just save changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [AutoMapper.org](https://automapper.org), take out a collection of the database objects you'd like to edit, merge with automapper and then save changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the way @Jouan Antoine said...buttons per CRUD activity or check the entity state:

```
 switch (custViewModel.State)
 {
    case State.Added:
     break;
    case State.Unchanged:
     break;
    case State.Modified:
    break;
    case State.Deleted:
    break;
    case State.Detached:
    break;
  }
```

your grid:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this please. I am not allowed to make any database transactions until the user is confident with their changes on the grid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in regards to confident with their changes on the grid?? You should apply validation (both client-side and server-side) prior to doing any transactions. This will ensure your business rules are applied.

Comment: By confident I mean the users should be able to reverse back all the changes that they have made prior to "saving" their changes. They should be able to reverse some or all of their changes before it is saved in the database. Therefore, I can have only have one button that does all the changes in this particular scenario.

So you might changes A lastname and someone else phone number and then add a new customer and that is fine but these actions cannot be saved promptly and they can only happen together.

Comment: That's going to be tough to do without storing the preliminary changes in the database. I would highly recommend creating staging tables in your database and save the changes in those tables. Once the user accepts the changes, then move the data from the staging to the actual tables. You need a way to store everything prior to hitting the accept button. How are you doing your CRUD actions like adding and updating? You have to provide the user some way to enter/change info and save it.

Comment: I save all the changes in the object list (List<Customer>) in memory before user hits the accept button. I am surprised because I expected a list update in EF to be a lot more effortless.

I have no problem for CRUD operations for entities with single items but if I need to update a list of elements in an entity going through multiple stages seems a lot of work for what EF was intended to be.

Comment: It's meant to process a single entity at a time. You can do a foreach on the list and just SaveChanges() on each item in the collection. Not very efficient. You should implement a transaction for rolling back the changes. I think it's under context.Database.BeginTransaction()